# Difference between $(N+P)/N$ and $P/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If $N$ and $P$ are submodules of the $A$-module $M$ (where $A$ is a commutative ring with unity), why is there a difference between $(N+P)/N$ and $P/N$?

If $x\in (N+P)/N$ then $x=n+p+N=p+N$ for some $n \in N$ and $p\in P$. So actually $x \in P/N$ right?
Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: If $P/N$ makes sense, then there is no difference, as then $P + N = P$.

Comment: Ok now i understand. So i only write $ N+P/N$ if i want to divide out by $N $ but $N$ is not a $P$-submodule, right?

Comment: You mean when $N$ is not contained in $P$.

Comment: Yes! How can i close this?

Comment: No need to close it. It is a fine question, which you could for example answer yourself now.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, there is a canonical isomorphism:
\begin{align*}P/N\cap P &\longrightarrow(P+N)/N\\ x+N\cap P & \longmapsto x+N\end{align*}

Also, there's a bijection between submodules of $M/N$ and submodules of $M$ *that contain* $N$, and $P$ is not supposed to contain $N$. However, by the canonical homomorphism $\,p\colon M\longrightarrow M/N$, $p(P)$ is a submodule of $M/N$, and 
$$p^{-1}\bigl(p(P)\bigr)=P+N. $$

Comment: I don't understand what this answer has to do with the question. (The OP is clearly confused with some notation.)

Comment: I intended to place the question in its context: mentioning $N+P/P$ inevitably evokes the canonical isomorphism, and  I think the O.P. wouldn't have asked the question if he/she had it in mind.